# Implementing scd2 in dbt using aws redshift, how do I define conditional natural keys?

Tags: amazon-redshift, etl, dbt

Implementing scd2 in dbt using aws redshift. How do I define conditional natural keys?

`unique_id = ['crm_id', 'curr_recrd_flg', 'actve_flg']`

I want to provide conditions like `curr_recrd_flg = 'Y' and actve_flg = 'Y'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbt can automate the creation of an SCD Type-2 table from a dimension table using its [`snapshot`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/snapshots) feature.

First, you define your snapshot in a `.sql` file inside of a directory called `snapshots` inside of your project directory:

```sql
-- snapshots/my_snapshot.sql
{% snapshot my_snapshot() %}
{{
    config(
      target_database='analytics',
      target_schema='snapshots',
      unique_key='crm_id',

      strategy='timestamp',
      updated_at='updated_at',
    )
}}
-- QUERY TEXT HERE
{% endsnapshot %}
```

The query in your snapshot definition can do anything. In your case, it seems like you want to filter on the "current record" fields, so that would look like:

```sql
-- snapshots/my_snapshot.sql
{% snapshot my_snapshot() %}
{{
    config(
      target_database='analytics',
      target_schema='snapshots',
      unique_key='crm_id',

      strategy='timestamp',
      updated_at='updated_at',
    )
}}
select *
from {{ source('my_source', 'my_table') }}
where curr_recrd_flg = 'Y' and actve_flg = 'Y'
{% endsnapshot %}
```

Then you can execute `dbt snapshot` at the command line, and dbt will capture the rows returned by your query. Executing `dbt snapshot` again will execute the query again and update the snapshot table with any changes, in the style of SCD-2.

Comment: what would be the best way to apply SCD-2 on a dimension table instead of creating a separate copy (snapshot table)?